# How are dates handled in sequelize

Tags: javascript, date, sequelize.js

My application requires clients from various time zones to set a time which is stored in an object in sequelize. For example, Client A from Timezone A chooses a time, is the time stored in the clients timezone, or the servers timezone when it is stored in sequelize? And if so, when Client B who is in time zone B wants to view the object that Client A created, how do I localize it to their timezone? Or do I have to store the date as a unix timestamp and then localize on the client side?

Comment: I will suggest to store it as a standard UTC timezone in database, and show user according to their timezone.

Comment: Is the date stored as utc in sequelize by default?

Comment: The question should be "Is the date stored as UTC in my database?" So what is a  database you use?